# How to get user ID from an open SAP GUI session?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I need to get the user ID into VBA code.

Like on the picture:

[image]

I tried

```
UserId = Session.FindById("wnd[0]").User
```

But it failed. What's the right way?

Comment: I think we need a bit more information to be able to help with this

Comment: Is this the Excel that’s embedded in an ALV list or some other connected SAP source? You’re showing SAPGui but but how is that interacting with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even easier would be:

```
UserId = Session.Info.User
```

Answer (score 0):

This proved to be easy:

```
Sub Getuser()



Dim SapGuiAuto
Dim SetApp
Dim Connection
Dim Session



Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SetApp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SetApp.Children(0)
Set Session = Connection.Children(0)

Session.FindById("wnd[0]").Maximize
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[4]/menu[11]").Select

MsgBox Session.FindById("wnd[1]/usr/txtSYST-UNAME").Text
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").Press

End Sub
```